# Find the simple 3D solid associated with these views

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

[image: this is related to engineering graphics, its a very simple 3D shape!]
Find the simple 3D solid associated with these views. It is given that there are no hidden lines (lines which are not visible from the side or top view).

Comment: There is a range of answers for this although the two answers posted so far cite the most common geometry that fits the requirement.

Comment: No hidden lines.

Comment: @KinjalJain is that side view what the shape would look like from all 4 sides?

Comment: is the inner square of the top view actually a hole that passes entirely through the object?

Comment: Don't know why this is too broad. As far as I can tell there is only one correct answer that doesn't require hidden lines. I'd post it but you put it on hold for some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modeled a solution in my CAD software. Here are some shaded views:

[image]

Just for completeness, here are the drawing views that this part produces:

[image]

---

Edit:

Just to clarify, the other solutions posted suggested this part as a solution:

[image]

However, notice the extra lines in the produced drawing. These lines would also appear in the "table with a hole in the middle" solution, so these are not correct.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was trying to suggest, although I thought a half circle as the front profile might work instead of a bell curve. +1 from me!

Comment: I had a similar shape in mind with my "bell curve" answer.

Comment: Regarding the "hidden lines problem", you can simply fill the hole with a flat cube. The edges in the middle would remain as they are.

Comment: If you fill the hole with a flat cube to get rid of the hidden lines, you will also remove two of the solid lines from the top view.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be,

> A table with a hole in the middle? The side view is the table turned upside down

Comment: no...In that case there will be hidden lines in side view

Comment: @KinjalJain it could still be a table with two legs though

Comment: how would you get the inner square in top view then?

Comment: @KanakPatel Hmm I guess that would count as hidden lines.

Answer (score 3):

> A 2 legged (thanks to Engineer Toast, it's simpler to draw) table with a hole in the middle.
> [image]

Comment: It could also be a two-legged table.

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes, but who would buy that? Maybe people buing a table with a hole ....

Comment: There are tables with two legs. Here's a [square end table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PAoBD.jpg).

Comment: no.. assume that there are no hidden lines in them.

Comment: @KanakPatel You mean the drawing above is wrong?

Comment: @Sleafar I think this isn't the right answer because the side view would be upside down.

Comment: This cannot be the case as the legs would produce lines along the length (on the inner side of the legs, adjacent to the square hole in the middle). Hard to explain without a drawing.

Comment: @dberm22 In this case your solution is probably the correct one.

Comment: @Trenin Just to be pedantic, the asker did not specify the orientation of the side view. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I trashed my crappy picture to ask a question instead. I don't know if anyone else will benefit from it, but I would like to learn personally.

In the picture below, if there was a hole through the center of the shape, the hidden lines would *have* to be show like this? I very well could be incorrect in my statement.

To my understanding @dberm22 and @alexmc pictures would have to be drawn like this because the lines making the hole are hidden behind the wall, which is not the original side view.

Please correct if I'm wrong and give a little explanation so I can screw my heads on right! -Thanks

> [image]

Another thought was (Maybe this can help someone)  if you look really close at the side view, you'll notice the inside of both the "legs" have a little extra line to them.  I don't know if that's a mess up on the picture or if it has significant value to the solution!!

Comment: Was looking at some comments from @SirParselot and saw mine would have hidden lines based off the hole in the middle. Doh.

Comment: Oh jeez, you're right. My drawings are missing hidden lines. Why didn't my CAD program alert me?? Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious to see the answer now if my thinking isn't wrong. That's a really tricky shape.

Answer (score 0):

Picture a cube.  Remove a square cylendar from the middle so it looks like the top view.  Now pass it through a half circle, or similar curve, cutting away much of the cube.  The key is that the sides need to be cut down enough so that the center gap is showing like in the second picture.

From the front, it will look like a half circle.  From the top, still looks like a square donut.  And from the side, a U.

Sorry, I don't have any drawing tools at my disposal.